# Is there a way for activating live-updaintg?

Tags: bug

I'm not sure this is the right place for asking this question. So please forgive me if it isn't.

Till yesterday I was used to have live-updating working with `Ask Different`.
Since today it doesn't show anymore the number of new or updated questions.
Is there a way for re-enabling it?

I read on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148430/stackoverflow-com-questions-is-not-updating) that, due to the performance reasons, it is disabled for `Stack Overflow`. Could it be the same for `Ask Different` (since today :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer with a definitive yes, but are you referring to the "2 questions" with new activity item that shows up when your current page is out of date?

The site developers should see this bug report and answer definitively, but we share the majority of the code with all the non-SO sites so it's extremely likely we are coded the same as stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that message. Now it works again. The curious thing is that I haven't done anything :-)

Comment: Sounds like the _very definition_ of a server side issue.